# simple time countdown string

Tags: java, android, time

i am sorry for asking question that already answered in other post.

i already have tick method running each second, since i don't know about time format, i only display counter (int variable type) from 1800 (30 minutes) , subtract it one (sec) by each tick , until 0.

can you teach me how to make it to display 30:00, 29:59 .. instead of 1800,1799 until 00:00 ..?

if possible, i don't want to implement any other method to get it done. if you have any idea how to make this possible as simple as possible.. e.g by using time or date type

thank you.

Comment: Get minutes from seconds and arrange.

Comment: Why don't you just calculate it yourself? Dividing by 60 is not difficult. Why is your first impulse to ask here instead?

Comment: how to divide it accurately, how to make 1799 become 29:59 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `timedelta()` method from the `datetime` module. You can use it as follows :

```
import datetime

your_nicely_formated_countdown_value = datetime.timedelta(seconds=your_current_tick_value))
```

For instance,

```
import datetime
print(str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=300)))
# => '0:05:00'
```

Comment: i can't import datetime ... how to find it ?

Comment: What version of Python are you using ? datetime should be embedded in your Python installation AFAIK

Comment: @NNzz where does Python come in to play here?